# how to use fastrand in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, random, numbers

I'd like to use `fastrand` library provided on [this](https://github.com/lemire/fastrand) GitHub page, which works fine when used to generate random numbers one at a time. For instance,

```
#pip install fastrand==1.2.4
import fastrand

print(fastrand.pcg32bounded(1001))
975
```

However, I would like to use this method in a numpy array to generate multiple numbers for certain indices where the upper bound is the number existing in the corresponding index. Suppose I have a 2 by 5 numpy array.

```
import fastrand
arr = np.array([[8, 7, 4, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9, 7, 9]])
print(arr,"\n")

[[8 7 4 9 9]
 [9 9 9 7 7]]
```

Now, I substract random numbers for the first two numbers in the second row.  I can easily do this by using `np.random.randint` as shown below.

```
arr[1,:2]-=  np.random.randint(arr[1,:2]) 
print(arr)
[[8 7 4 9 9]
 [4 1 9 7 7]]
```

My goal is to use `fastrand` instead of `np.random.randint` to increase the performance. Is this possible by any chance?

Edit: On a second note, another issue is how to place a lower bound on the generated random number. However, I can ask this question as a new post if needed.

Comment: why aren't you using the numpy function to create all the random values at once?

Comment: how is it going to be helpful in my case? I assume you mean that I should use ````np.random.randint(arr)```` and do the indexing later?

Comment: I was thinking of `arr = np.random.randint(2,10,(2,5))`. for the first step.  `np.random.randint(arr[1,:2])` creates multiple random values, using the array slice as upper bound.  `np.random` is best for generating many random values at a time.  The python `random` is better if you want just one value per call.

Comment: I guess I'm a little bit confused. ````np.random.randint(arr[1,:2])```` creates exactly two random numbers since I only intend to update the first two entries of the second row. However, what you suggest creates a whole bunch of random numbers as a 2 by 5 numpy array without taking into consideration the upper bounds. I want to make sure that I generate a random number upper bounded by the entry in the original place.

Comment: You create `arr` with a nested list; I was wondering why you didin't use `randint` with a `size` parameter.  I'm not suggesting any changes to the second use of `randint`.  That already creates multiple values.

Comment: Ohh that's just an MWE. I read my data from a txt file. The array and the set of indices are all read from a txt file.

Comment: I don't know anything about `fastrand`, but assume it's more like the base python `random`, in that it has to be called once for each random value.  For a few values such an iteration may be faster than the array method, but it won't scale well.

Comment: ````fastrand```` is way faster than ````randint```` in terms of the performance, but I could not figure out how to use it in a numpy array. That was the main question.

Comment: *"Ohh that's just an MWE. ..."*  So in your real problem, you don't generate `arr` randomly?  You read it from a file?  Your question would be less confusing if you fixed that part of the sample code to be, say, `arr = np.array([[8, 7, 4, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9, 7, 9]])`.  Then it is clearer that what you are really interested in is updating the first two values in the second row.  (That's assuming I understand what you've said so far in the comments.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Updated the post accordingly. Your interpretation is correct. I'm trying to find a faster way to generate random numbers for certain indices in a given numpy array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to import `fastrand`, but I think this function simulates its action.  I'm not sure about the end point adjustment.  Here I assume the desired range is [0,n), not including the end point as `numpy` does.  Tweak as necessary.

```
In [52]: def fastrand(n):
    ...:     return random.randint(0,n-1)
    ...:
```

That can be substituted into your initial list comprehension as:

```
In [53]: arr = np.array([[fastrand(8)+2 for i in range(5)]for j in range(2)])
In [54]: arr
Out[54]: 
array([[6, 7, 2, 6, 2],
       [5, 3, 9, 4, 7]])
```

As I claimed in the comments, you can just as well generate all random numbers with one call.  For small arrays it may be slower, but it should scale better.  But you'll have to do your own time tests.

```
In [55]: np.random.randint(2,10,(2,5))
Out[55]: 
array([[9, 5, 8, 6, 7],
       [8, 7, 7, 9, 8]])
```

The `randint` with array upper bound is:

```
In [56]: np.random.randint(arr[0,:2])
Out[56]: array([2, 4])
In [57]: np.random.randint(arr[0,:2])
Out[57]: array([5, 0])
```

with a scalar random int generator you'd have to use a list comprehension as before.  Here it's just 1d:

```
In [58]: [fastrand(i) for i in arr[0,:2]]
Out[58]: [4, 6]
In [59]: [fastrand(i) for i in arr[0,:2]]
Out[59]: [5, 4]
```

Again, there's a trade off between the code of iteration, and the slower `numpy` setup.

Comment: How can ````[fastrand(i) for i in arr[0,:2]]```` be faster than  what I am already using as ````np.random.randint(arr[1,:2])````? The whole reason why I'd like to use ````fastrand```` is that it is way faster than ````random.randint````.

Comment: In my real data set, I have hundreds of thousands of rows and columns.

Comment: You were insisting on using `fastrand` in your problem.  I tried to demonstrate how.  I didn't promise a speed improvement. That's for you to test.

Comment: Oh okay, I just realized that if I arrange the fastrand method that you defined by using the original library, then it should work.

Comment: You were right about "Again, there's a trade-off between the code of iteration, and the slower NumPy setup." It turned out that NumPy is faster than using a method with ````fastrand.```` I guess I'm doomed at this point.  The original way took 49 secs, but using ````fastrand```` in a method took 174 secs in my end.